# Android creating folder at the root sdcard path(/sd_card/test/) fails. Even after granting write permission

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio, kotlin

I need to create a folder in Sd card path. Even after granting write permission. It is not working.
I got the sd_card path

```
    fun getExternalCardDirectory(): JSONObject? {
    if (isSDCardPresent(context)) {
        val storageManager = context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE)
        try {
            val storageVolumeClazz = Class.forName("android.os.storage.StorageVolume")
            val getVolumeList = storageManager.javaClass.getMethod("getVolumeList")
            val getPath = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getPath")
            val isRemovable = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("isRemovable")
            val isMounted = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getState")
            val result = getVolumeList.invoke(storageManager) as Array<*>

            result.forEach {
                if (isRemovable.invoke(it) as Boolean) {
                    val card_state = isMounted.invoke(it) as String
                    var path = File(getPath.invoke(it) as String).absolutePath
                    val sdCardInfo = JSONObject()
                    sdCardInfo.put("path", path)
                    sdCardInfo.put("state", card_state)

                    return sdCardInfo
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }
    return null
}
```

confirming the Write permission

```
val writeStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    if (writeStoragePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d("TAG","Permission is granted");  // permission grant confirmed prints
    }else {
        Log.d("TAG","No Permission is granted");
    }
```

**Creating a folder using mkdirs() fails on sd_card root path**

```
 val storagePath = getExternalCardDirectory.get("path") as String + File.separator + "Test"
 val targetDir = File(storagePath)

 if (targetDir.exists().not()) {
    targetDir.mkdirs()
 }
```

Anyone Please help me to get the re-solve it.

Comment: We have not had arbitrary filesystem access to removable storage since Android 4.4. Use the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: I add on what CommonsWare said that it's not sure that you can use SAF from version 11 (R) of Android if your app will be distributed by Play store. It seems that only apps that Play store moderators consider as "file manager" will be allowed to use SAF (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE): https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage

Comment: Also I have Implemented **scoped storage to save file in sd card**, it works cool in Android 10. But below sdk 29, `MediaStore.getExternalVolumeNames(context).last` to get sd card uri -> fails because getExternalVolumeNames was added in sdk 29.  @EasyJoinDev @CommonsWare

Comment: @CommonsWare, pls check -> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960036/android-studio-mediastore-below-sdk-29-save-image-in-sd-card-fails]