# Android Studio MediaStore, below SDK 29 save image in sd card fails

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-10.0, scoped-storage

I need to save image in sd_card's pictures directory below Android 10.I have implemented scoped storage & This code works in sdk 29 & above, because MediaStore.getExternalVolumeNames was added in sdk 29. 
Below sdk 29 how to get `getContentUri` of sd_card .

```
  val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, destinationFileName)
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + context.applicationContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
        }

        val storageVolume = if (AppPreferences(context).getSwitchExternalStorage()) MediaStore.getExternalVolumeNames(context).last() else MediaStore.getExternalVolumeNames(context).first()
        val bmp: Bitmap? = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(source)

        val collection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(storageVolume)
        val imageUri = context.contentResolver.insert(collection, values)

        context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(imageUri!!).use { out ->
            bmp?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
        }

        values.clear()
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
        context.contentResolver.update(imageUri, values, null, null)
```

**Please help me to fix this issue**

Comment: "Below sdk 29 how to get getContentUri of sd_card ." -- I would not do that. I would use standard file I/O prior to Android 10.

Comment: Below sdk 29 - If I use Standard File I/O, even after granting write permission, it is throwing permission denied. Java.File.not.found exception. I couldn't even create a directory using mkdirs(). **File("/sd_card/Pictures/test/).mkdirs()**is not working. Any idea 

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were working with external storage. We have not had reliable read/write access to arbitrary locations on removable storage since Android 4.4. You are welcome to use `getExternalFilesDirs()` (note the plural), as the second and subsequent entries in the `File` objects you get back are locations on removable storage to which you can read and write. Otherwise, use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`).

Comment: getExternalFilesDirs(null) of second will give path as sd_card/Android/data/package_name/files. Images saved in the path would not be visible in Gallery. Also ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT will require user to choose the path from picker - It's not needed in our case. Any solution other than this

Comment: "It's not good" -- IMHO, it is. It allows the user to choose where the content goes. "Any solution other than this" -- none that I am aware of.